# Question based solution suggestions - Design strategy

Tags: gui-design, interaction-design, ux-field, strategy

We have seen the rise of AI like Chat-GPT that can provide feasible solutions using pre-fed data. Also, I have seen multiple applications the user on what they want, and then suggesting services/products that could help them address their need.

What is this approach called in UX terms?

Answer (score 7):

This is called **Conversational UX**. The product asks a few questions to understand what the user is looking for.

For example, you can check and hotel booking app, Initially they ask where and how many. Based on that it gives you some suggestions. Adding AI to the product can analyze the user more deeply and can able to provide the best suggestions instead of more suggestions.